# C2296: '|': illegal, left operand has type 'float'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am trying to compare, in a clean and FAST way (by logic) if three variables are 0, they are all floating point numbers, IEEE 754.

```
float x;
float y;
float z;

if(((x | y | z) == 0.0f)) { ... }
```

But, I keep getting:

```
main.cpp(15): error C2296: '|': illegal, left operand has type 'float'
main.cpp(15): error C2297: '|': illegal, right operand has type 'float'
main.cpp(18): error C2296: '|': illegal, left operand has type 'float'
main.cpp(18): error C2297: '|': illegal, right operand has type 'float'
```

I read something about,

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559
std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()
std::fabs()
```

and
Epsilon `10^−7`

Comment: What's wrong with `if ((x == 0.0f) || (y == 0.0f) || (z == 0.0f)) { ... }`?

Comment: As an additional note: floats allow values of +0 and -0. So the number can be zero without all bits being zero.

Comment: Have you checked how the `|` operator is defined?

Comment: If those variables have been used in arithmetic operations, the chances of them being exactly zero are slim to none. Using an epsilon for comparison is definitely the way to go. And not to try to optimize it, always strive for clear, readable and maintainable code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, how can the Epsilon `10^-7` be used with three variables?

Comment: @JohnSmith: If your calculation has caused the result to go off by 8 orders of magnitude, you ought to revisit it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I know that the `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` can be used to compare two variables, but I have three.

Comment: @JohnSmith " I know that the std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() can be used to compare two variables" You what ?! - that's not at all what that constant is for.

Comment: `if (x*y*z==0)` is the non-obvious short form. Breaks down if any of them is NaN (Not A Number).

Comment: @MSalters: And that requires only one of the variables to be zero. So there's a nice bug for the intern to fix.

Comment: @Bathsheba, so in a context of quadratic polynomial equation, I'd use the epsilon on a discriminant ?

Comment: The number of variables doesn't matter, as you compare each variable one by one. And there are many tutorials and examples on using an epsilon to compare against values (typically zero) all over the Internet.

Comment: @MSalters, that's not a good one, if I want to go that way, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Bathsheba, so in a context of quadratic polynomial equation, I'd use the epsilon on a discriminant ? Right ?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Under IEEE754 the evaluation of the roots of a quadratic polynominal must yield the closest floating point value at every point in the calculation. (`std::sqrt` is one of those special functions under IEEE754, `std::pow` is not.) The path you take in calculating the descriminant depends on how large b * b is compared to 4 * a * c (normal notation).

Comment: @Bathsheba, for a `b * b` I am actually doing `std::pow(b,2)` not sure this is really good now.

Comment: @JohnSmith: No it isn't. Under IEEE754 `b * b` gives you the closest floating point value to the square of `b`. `std::pow(b, 2)` carries no such guarantee.

Comment: Even with IEEE-754, the difference between two approximately-equal numbers is necessarily imprecise. See [this simple solution](https://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Quadratics.pdf) how to avoid a problem in the discriminant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise operators are only defined for *integral types*. A `float` is not an integral type.

Don't micro-optimise like this. Write your intention clearly, and leave the optimisation strategy to the compiler.

Comment: I thought about a faster way, I have never tested with `floats` before.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Start with the obvious `(!x && !y! && !z)`, check the generated assembler, and try to beat the performance using a good profiling tool. You could put the one most likely to be zero at the start of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot perform a "bitwise OR" on floating point numbers.

If you really wanted to, you could directly inspect the bits representing the floating point numbers and perform integer comparisons on them, which is the sort of thing you might do on an embedded system with no FPU and no floating point library.

[image: structure of float and double]

See https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-ieee.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 for more.

Whilst that can be a fun endeavour, you're almost always better off making your code readable so that it can be maintained; leaving optimisation to the compiler.

In addition, I would personally almost never compare a floating point with zero, but check that its `abs` is less than a very small number.

Comment: Beware of signed zero and NaN if you go down this path for this particular problem.

Comment: Indeed - the sign bit would naturally be left out of the comparison, plus NaN and Infinity (all bits set in the exponent) would fail the zero test anyway.

Comment: We support such an embedded platform, and it turns out you don't need to follow IEEE754 bit patterns when you implement your own FP type.